# In Android, How do you clear the WI-FI list of networks in Settings via Java?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

In Android, How do you clear the WI-FI list of networks in Settings via Java?
I currently am successful to remove them all with this code, but when I go
into the phone, they all appear in the list still.  The manual way would
be to click on FORGET this network.  But I thought that is what I am achieving
in code below here:

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {

    wifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
    wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

....etc

Comment: Logically I agree that `removeNetwork(...)` ought to work but have you tried `disableNetwork(...)` which makes the network unavailable for association?

Comment: I'm even thinking, I might have to toggle wifi on/off once to reset the list on the phone after all of the networks are removed

Comment: Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml.