# Android: Temporarily connect to WiFi network?

Tags: android, wifi

when I connect to an 8open) WLAN network using this code:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration(); 
wifiConfig.BSSID =result.BSSID; // BSSID of detected network
wifiConfig.priority = 1; 
wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.NONE); 
wifiConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP); 
wifiConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN); 
wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE); 
wifiConfig.status=WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED; 

int netId = scanData.wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig); 
scanData.wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
```

...this WiFi connection is stored in list of preferred networks. So when I try that very often I get a really huge list of connections - and that's somethin I do not want.

So my question: how can I establish a connection to a WLAN network just temporarily and let Android not store it permanently? Or is there a way to remove such a network in case it is no longer needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disconnect from the network, just remove it from the stored list. See details here: [In Android, How do you clear the WI-FI list of networks in Settings via Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529066/in-android-how-do-you-clear-the-wi-fi-list-of-networks-in-settings-via-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could search if the wifiConfig is already saved, then remove it before connect: like this:

```
List <WifiConfiguration> wifiConf = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
int netId;
for(WifiConfiguration wf: wifiConf){
    if(wf.BSSID.equals(desiredBSSID)){
        netId = wf.networkId;
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(netId);
    }
}
```